# php zend framework2 sql execute query returns scalar

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework2, scalar

I have a query that i execute within zend framework 2

```
protected function getCityByZip($zip){
    $adapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('myConn');
    $sql = new Sql($adapter);
    $select = $sql->select();
    $select->from(array("cities" => "cities"))
           ->columns(array('cityName'))
           ->where(array("cityZip" => $zip));
    $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
    $result = $statement->execute();
    return $result;
}
```

i want to do something like

> executeScalar();

and get just a single value, and not a result set like i get here from using execute()

how is this possible?

Comment: blackbishop, i'm not sure i understood your question, but what i get is a resultSet(that needs to be iterated) with a single value, instead of just a result scalar

Comment: Sorry I've just understood what you need. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but if you want your function `getCityByZip($zip)` returns a single value you can do this :

```
protected function getCityByZip($zip){
    $adapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('myConn');
    $sql = new Sql($adapter);
    $select = $sql->select();
    $select->from(array("cities" => "cities"))
           ->columns(array('cityName'))
           ->where(array("cityZip" => $zip));
    $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
    $resultSet = $statement->execute();

    $current = $resultSet->current();
    
    return $current->cityName;
}
```

**EDIT :**

I think what you're looking for is the `fetchOne()` method which was in **ZF1** `DB Adapter` (see this [Fetching a Single Scalar from a Result Set](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.select.fetchone)) but **not in ZF2**. In ZF1 you could do this :

```
$db->fetchOne('SELECT cityName FROM users WHERE cityZip='.$zip);
```

But the equivalent, in ZF2,  takes several lines of code as the above function.

Comment: You could avoid the loop with `$current = $resultSet->current();`

Comment: thanks AlexP for the comment. i'm actually looking for a straightforward approach for returning just the single value? without the need to handle the whole resultSet.

Comment: @AlexP thanks for the remark ;-) I forgot that function. Edited my answer.